# Decrease lower range for distance filtering in job search

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Currently the "Distance" slider for [job searches](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs) bottoms out at 10 miles:

> [image]

That's a huge distance in an urban area.  Ideally it would be possible to go down all the way to one mile.  Moreover, for searches within cities, it would be nice to restrict results to exclude suburban surroundings and be strictly within "New York, NY" or "Washington, DC", not results in NJ or VA.

Comment: In a city, during rush hours, one mile means significantly more travel time  than outside it.

Comment: I agree with this being a problem. If I lived 10mi from my work it would take me over 2 hrs to reach it. I guess it would be different if I had a car and lived on the countryside in a country with high speed limits.

Comment: As far as I see, both you (when searching or otherwise) and all companies have to specify exact coordinates (or an address) for higher precision searching to work properly (this isn't currently happening / enforced, is it?).

Comment: @Dukeling as far as I know the team is currently using Yahoo's GeoPlanet Web Service for example [New York](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22New%20York%22&format=xml) - it does contain exact coordinates.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd My point is - if some company says "We're in New York", but actually they're in some suburb, it won't exactly work, and even if they aren't, isn't it still a fairly big place? And if you live on the outskirts of New York, you probably don't want the whole of New York, or a small radius from the centre of New York to show up, rather than just around where you live. The point of my point is - it may be useful to a very, very, very small group of people, unless all coordinates are made more precise, if they aren't already.

Comment: @Dukeling not sure but guess the Careers site does support exact location including street.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, NY, NY is not the same as "lower manhatten".  It'd be great if we could get that level of precision.  Without getting too far into the weeds, the main point is that 10 mile precision in an urban area is not useful.  And yes, there will be some companies that choose to game system and insist on being in "NY, NY" whilst really being in "Edison, NJ", but hopefully most won't, and that's enough for it to be useful.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about companies actually in a completely different state than listed, just in one of the suburbs or on the outskirts of a listed city (can they even specify a suburb? I don't have much familiarity with this). I'm not arguing that more than 10 mile precision is a bad idea, just that it won't be all that useful without a fair amount of work on the system, and location updates by all parties involved.